# pause playing youtube video when another is played?

Tags: html, mootools, youtube, youtube-api

I will have a large number of youtube videos active on a single webpage, presumably using the embed code from YouTube. (normal and/or iFrame)

I want the user only able to play one at a time. if one is running and another is played i need all other/s to stop/pause.

Is there a way to globally control all players in that way? Maybe with MooTools?

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=youtube#working_with_multiple_players and enable js api - its all in the docs. you can create a shim around the players that has native mootools events that can track clicks on the player but i cant get it to receive events from an embedded player - only the dynamically embedded ones. then again, i only tried for 3 mins. good luck

Comment: have you figured this out yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the [YouTube iFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

Basically you just need to set up a YT.Player instance for each video and set up an onStateChange event that stops the other player(s) if the given video starts.

e.g.

```
player1 = new YT.Player('player1', {
    events: {
      'onStateChange': function(e) { 
          if(e.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) player2.stopVideo(); }
    }
});
```

If you've got a lot of players, setting up a loop shouldn't be too tricky. 2 player demo available at http://torontoprogrammer.ca/demos/multiyoutube/

Comment: Hi! I'm trying to apply this, but, neither in the tutorials mentions about how to set up a YT.Player, and I try to use the examples in the pages and didnt work. Sry if this sounds dumb, im new at YTAPI

Comment: Someone please post full working code, maybe with the help of https://web.archive.org/web/20160406213323/http://torontoprogrammer.ca/demos/multiyoutube/